# "Dopo" nel senso di "da"

Tags: grammar

Ho trovato in un articolo di giornale la seguente frase:

> tomba abbandonata a 5 anni dopo la morte.

È corretto oppure si dovrebbe dire "a 5 anni dalla morte"?

Comment: O è un refuso per “tomba abbandonata 5 anni dopo la morte” o il titolista ha un'idea molto personale dell'italiano.

Comment: Purtroppo se cerchi la frase  esatta su web la trovi a proposito di Funari su diverse testate per questo mi è sorto il dubbio

Comment: Ho visto: ipotizzo che si siano copiate a vicenda o che abbiano ripreso tutte, copiandola letteralmente, una stessa notizia d'agenzia.

Comment: I titoli di giornale sono per definizione scritti in fretta e furia prima di stamparli, per cui sono famosi per contenere refusi (lo so, almeno la versione online potrebbero correggerla...), non baserei la mia conoscenza dell'italiano su di essi.

Comment: È un errore comune scegliere, tra due possibili costruzioni, né l'una né l'altra, bensì una mescolanza delle due. Nel caso che proponi, si potrebbe dire «5 anni dopo la morte» o, preferibile, «a 5 anni dalla morte».

Answer (score 4):

Visto che questa domanda è rimasta senza risposta per molto tempo (probabilmente perché c'è una difficoltà oggettiva nel leggere la mente di chi ha scritto quel titolo), provo a rischiare e a dire la mia:

**No**, non è corretto. È probabile però che il titolista abbia fatto confusione tra due espressioni, ambedue corrette:

> [Una] tomba abbandonata 5 anni dopo la morte.

e

> [Una] tomba abbandonata a 5 anni dalla morte.

Comment: Mi sono permesso di modificare sia perché non trovo chi sia “la giornalista” (in rete trovo un articolo del “Messaggero” senza autore, ma è probabile che l'origine sia qualche lancio d'agenzia), che perché in genere i titoli non sono scritti dall'autore del pezzo stesso.

Answer (score -1):

Credo che *dopo* e *dalla* in questo caso siano utilizzabili come sinonimi in quanto entrambi reggono un complemento di tempo e entrambi hanno il significato di 'a partire dalla morte'.